# Preferred aproach to implementing game pause

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is a good way to implement pause in a game?

I can come up with these two ideas:

1. Using `FindObjectsOfType<IPausable>()`
2. Having a pause action on the `Pauser` class and get every object that can be paused subscribe to it

I understand both approaches would work fine, but wouldn't know which one to lean towards to.

Thanks

Comment: If you're just looking for something quick and dirty `Time.timeScale = 0` might work for your purpose. Won't work with everything, though.

Comment: Looking for something more robust here, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

I think interfaces might be a good solution here.

You could create an IPauseable interface and have any thing you want to pause implement the IPausable interface that way every object you have subscribe to your PauseManager or such can be treat the same.

```
public interface IPausable{
  // interface members
  void Pause();
  bool isPaused();
  void UnPause();
 }
```

Then you can iterate through the list of subscribed objects and doing something like (pseudo code untested to show the idea)

```
   for (int i = 0; i< subScribedComponents.Length; i++)
   {
        if (subScribedComponents[i] is IPausable)
       {
            IPausable pauseInterface = subScribedComponents[i] as IPausable;

            pauseInterface .Pause();
        }
    }
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that any class that implements IPausable must provide how they will execute those methods themselves and they can all be treat the same way, so whether its a Character or On-Screen timer if it implements the interface you know you've at some point provided a way to pause that particular object.

**To directly answer the original question I would vote for the subscriber/publisher method (2)** because the first option will have you looping over every object, some not pausable at all, if you go the second route you will be only operating on things you want pausing and not iterating every object in the scene.

Comment: Hey Pheonix2105, thanks for answering. I opted for my first solution mainly because 1. In my case the everything that needs pausing is going to live in the active scene. 2. Only the Game manager class can call the Pause method.